# Wordpress Woocommerce скидка на первый заказ

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сам вопрос в название, я не знаю как это делать. По сути, нам нужно как-то идентифицировать пользователя, что-бы при следующем заказе не давать уже скидку. Для этого есть много плагинов регистрации, окей, но как с помощью них сделать скидку, я не знаю.

Возможно я плохо гуглил, но ответа я не нашёл. Нужна помощь. Может быть какой-то плагин, может быть код вставить.

Это срочно, прошу помощи.

Comment: Если я создам 10 аккаунтов, то могу купить 10 раз со скидкой?

Comment: Сделайте промокод и не морочьте себе голову

Comment: Промокод не подходит, на счёт 10 аккаунтов, да всё равно. Пусть будет 10 раз со скидкой. Там-же в любом случае, адрес указываем один и тот-же для доставки, по этому можно как-то считать. Меня не интересуют другие способы, нужно именно так.